# Connecting GIF and text with hover

Tags: html, css

I struggle to get my hover to connect with a GIF. Obviously, it does not show when I set `display:none` on the text, but I thought the `#witch:hover ~ text{ display:block}` really would work.

```css
    #animcontainer {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  #witch {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2950px;
    height: 150px;
    bottom: 50px;
    z-index: 2` #hello {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      border: 25px;
      padding: 1.5rem;
      background-color: orange;
      left: 3100px;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      bottom: 200px;
      left: 2900px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #witch:target~#hello {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="animcontainer">
    <div id="hello"> text</div>
    <img id="potato" src="url">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question, edit the snippet and confirm that this is your actual code. There are several syntax errors and a stray back-tick in there. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/289905).

Comment: At `left: 2900px;` this is for a projector?